# Capture audio in C++ from a microphone

Tags: c++, windows, audio, record

I want doing a program to capture and process audio from a mic. I search in Internet but is so confuse.
Do you know what class and functions i have use to capture audio in c++? If you give me some samples i will thank you.

I use windows 7 and visual studio 2012

Comment: Using what OS? Somehow I think that's relevant.

Comment: I suggest to extend your tags with the OS you are  using.

Comment: sorry, Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple options, at first you have the choice to use a larger framework or the Winapi directly. If you choose the latter then have a look at this [**tutorial**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208153-sound-recorder-using-the-low-level-windows-api-in-c/), it shows it better than I could.

Comment: thanks, i am goint to read this

Comment: Sadly this page has no download. You have to copy 3 files by hand from the website to a new Win32 project. But it works. Even on Windows 7.